# How to pre-fill values that the user has entered into the fields in-case validation fails

Tags: php

I' am posting the html form to a php script contact.php and doing other validation and sending email.

**My Question**
Let's suppose if theirs an error that occured in the php script contact.php so I will use

```
header("Locations: /contact-us.php?status=error");
```

**How can pre-fill the form values that the user has entered into the fields after the error occurs ?**

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="/forms/contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="wipit" id="wipit" value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Script**

```
if( isset($_POST["wipit"]) and trim($_POST["wipit"]) == ""){
   /* Other Validations goes here */
}
```

Comment: The normal thing to do is to _not_ redirect.

Comment: Don't redirect, it will clear the $_POST.

Comment: Yes, it will. I think I have to use SESSION thats my only option here I guess.